# SQLITE and foreign key support

Tags: spring, sqlite, spring-data

Anyone had any success in getting sqlite and spring working with foreign key support enabled? By default foreign key support is disabled in sqlite. The documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html mentions that you have to enable it for each database connection separately. I am sure that the version of sqlite I have got supports foreign keys (downloaded it only last week).

to test: If I key in PRAGMA foreign_keys; I get back 0. Which means foreign keys is switched off but support for it exists.

My datasource is defined in spring as :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverclass}"/>
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
</bean>
```

How do I enable foreign keys through spring configuration?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly turning it on on the console? So type ``PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`` and then ``PRAGMA foreign_keys;`` to see if there really is support. It should dosplay ``1``.

Comment: @Tim I know this is old, but just in case anybody is looking at this, typing `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` into the console (I'm assuming you mean in the sqlite console) won't work, as foreign keys need to be enabled for each individual connection.
If I open a console, set foreign keys to be on, then open a second console, foreign keys will be enabled in the first console, but not in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on one of the spring forums:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name = "connectionInitSqls">
    <list><value>**PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON**</value></list>
    </property>
    ...
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I was a little confused recently with the same problem.

There are at least 2 solutions that I know of using Spring Boot (I assume similar solutions for regular Spring). The salient point with Sqlite foreign key support is `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` is valid on a *per-connection basis*. (i.e. If I have two open connections to the database, and I set foreign key support to be `On` in my first connection, the first connection will have foreign key support, but the second connection will not.

**Solution 1** 
From the [Spring Boot reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database):

> If you use the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` or `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` 
>   “starters”, you automatically get a dependency to HikariCP.

Spring Boot automatically creates a `DataSource` bean for you using `HikariCP` as the default driver. `HikariCP` itself delegates to the appropriate driver [based on its configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby).

Spring Boot expects, at minimum, `spring.datasource.url` be set in `application.properties`. Hikari configuration settings can also be set in the properties file, under `spring.datasource.hikari.<config-key>`, when `config-key` is one of the [Hikari configuration keys](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby). Knowing this, using Spring Boot we can use the following `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:path/to/db/database_file.db
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionInitSql=PRAGMA foreign_keys=1
```

And the following DAO (I'm using `JdbcTemplate`):

```
@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate JDBC_TEMPLATE;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleArticleDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.JDBC_TEMPLATE = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertObject(MyObject object) {
        JDBC_TEMPLATE.update(
            *...insert object into some table*
        )
    }
}
```

Spring Boot will create and inject the `dataSource` bean using Hikari as the DataSource, and Hikari will execute `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` for every connection it creates, ensuring that foreign key support is always enabled.

**Solution 2** 
You can define a `DataSource` bean in your `@Configuration` class for Spring Boot, and programmatically set the foreign key support by directly using the [Xerial JDBC driver](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc):

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        SQLiteDataSource ds = new SQLiteDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:path/to/db/database_file.db");
        SQLiteConfig config = ds.getConfig();
        config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
        ds.setConfig(config);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    ...other bean definitions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just today using Spring Boot 2.2.2 with SQLite and plain `JdbcTemplate`.

Implementing solution 2 from Patrick Tyler's answer broke all kind of things in my tests. I am still not sure why, because the very simple test to verify foreign key support was enabled did succeed.

Alternatively, I tried to configure `spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql` but this did not work either.

Alas, what did finally work was to add the following to `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        foreign_keys: true
```

This can be verified with a simple test case:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SqliteTests {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @DisplayName("Check for foreign key support in the SQLite backend")
  @Test
  void testSqliteForEnabledForeignKeySupport() {
    final var result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("PRAGMA foreign_keys", Integer.class);
    assertEquals(1, result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 3**

When using Hikari (by default in spring boot 2+) we can simply configure Xerial JDBC Driver with the following entry in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.foreign_keys=true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
            'foreign_keys' => true,
        ],
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).